# VS Code Path error because of nordic letter

Tags: visual-studio-code, path

I manage an user with the nordic letter 'ø' in the name. This letter is also part of the name of the user in C:, where VS code is downloaded. When trying to run a script, I get a path error message which I believe is rooted in the username in C:, as others I know have run the exact script without any problems (they don't have any nordic letters in their names).

Since I'm unable to find any, I'm looking for a solution that pertains to VS code - i.e. is there any way to configure some settings for it to be able to run the script? Or am I just in bad luck and need to change the path and have an user without "ø" in the name?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: what kind of script and with what kind of runtime?